# How can I restore the encrypted partition table of my LUKS encrypted ubuntu partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, encryption, restore

I accidentially deleted the partition table of one SSD. I am trying to restore everything with [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and when I run `analyze` it shows me the following after some percent of the process:

```
MS Data                     2048     976895     974848
MS Data                   976896     980991       4096
                         490689665 44640848976 44150159312 [~^ }
```

after the process terminated it shows me

```
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P MS Data                     2048     976895     974848
 P MS Data                   976896     980991       4096
```

When I then write the table via testdisk it restores only 2.1 MB of the around 480GB partition. When I reboot it shows the decryption screen, but it does not take my password (yes, I am sure it is the correct one).

I think the ending of the second partition is just wrong, but no idea how to change that savely. When I then perform a deep search on the second found partition it shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 480 GB / 447 GiB - CHS 58369 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>D MS Data                     2046     976893     974848
 D MS Data                     2048     976895     974848
 D MS Data                   280580    1255427     974848
 D MS Data                   280616    1255463     974848
 D MS Data                   280684    1255531     974848
 D MS Data                   280758    1255605     974848
 D MS Data                   280800    1255647     974848
 D MS Data                   280968    1255815     974848
 D MS Data                   281004    1255851     974848
 D MS Data                   281070    1255917     974848
 D MS Data                   281118    1255965     974848
 D MS Data                   281168    1256015     974848
 D MS Data                   281224    1256071     974848
 D MS Data                   281292    1256139     974848
 D MS Data                   285230    1260077     974848
 D MS Data                   285250    1260097     974848
 D MS Data                   285272    1260119     974848
 D MS Data                   285292    1260139     974848
 D MS Data                   285448    1260295     974848
 D MS Data                   285512    1260359     974848
 D MS Data                   285620    1260467     974848
 D MS Data                   285784    1260631     974848
 D MS Data                   285802    1260649     974848
 D MS Data                   285862    1260709     974848
 D MS Data                   285902    1260749     974848
 D MS Data                   285924    1260771     974848
 D MS Data                   285946    1260793     974848
 D MS Data                   285966    1260813     974848
 D MS Data                   286100    1260947     974848
 D MS Data                   286250    1261097     974848
 D MS Data                   289768    1264615     974848
 D MS Data                   289864    1264711     974848
 D MS Data                   289892    1264739     974848
 D MS Data                   289912    1264759     974848
 D MS Data                   289930    1264777     974848
 D MS Data                   294298    1269145     974848
 D MS Data                   294394    1269241     974848
 D MS Data                   294422    1269269     974848
 D MS Data                   294442    1269289     974848
 D MS Data                   294674    1269521     974848
 D MS Data                   294696    1269543     974848
 D MS Data                   294746    1269593     974848
 D MS Data                   294792    1269639     974848
 D MS Data                   294838    1269685     974848
 D MS Data                   294888    1269735     974848
 D MS Data                   294936    1269783     974848
 D MS Data                   294968    1269815     974848
 D MS Data                   295024    1269871     974848
 D MS Data                   295084    1269931     974848
 D MS Data                   295136    1269983     974848
 D MS Data                   976896     980991       4096
 D MS Data                   978944     983039       4096



Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
                P=Primary  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
ext4 blocksize=1024 Large_file Sparse_SB Backup_SB, 499 MB / 476 MiB
```

How can I restore that partition table of my LUKS encrypted ubuntu 20.04 partition? It was an encrypted LVM install on the whole SSD.

Update:
This is what it restores when I create the found partitions directly with TestDisk:
[image: Screenshot of Disks GUI with created partition table]

Comment: How many partitions did you have on the disk; what were their sizes approximately?

Comment: I only had the ubuntu lvm on the full disk. The disk has 480GB.

Comment: If I remember correctly I simply used Ubuntu's full disk encryption https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291268/full-disk-encryption-with-20-04

Comment: Try perhaps [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411587/17660).

Comment: I tried to follow the answer of @harrymc, but when running the following command I receive an error that I don't understand: ```sudo losetup -o 0x1dd00000 -r -f /dev/nvme0n1
losetup: /dev/nvme0n1: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory```

Comment: The name of your device is different from `/dev/nvme0n1`?

Answer (score 0):

Use fdisk and restore the partition exactly as testdisk found it. With encryption turned on.

This should make the partitions readable and mountable.

Comment: The problem seems to be that TestDisk finds the wrong ending of the LUKS partition. I can directly restore it in TestDisk, but the partition dev/sdb2 is only 2.1MB large...

Comment: @Anno use the beginning of the partition and make it as long as possible (till next partition or till the end of the disk but limited to megabytes) with fdisk.

Comment: how? What would be the command?

Comment: @Anno using fdisk.